# Clearing buttons .Text on Android issue

Tags: java, android

I am making a tic tac toe app for android, and when I run my clear buttons function:

```
    b1.setText("");
    b1.setEnabled(true);
    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

To just clear the text for the buttons and enable them for a new game, the space in between the buttons disappears and the 9 button grid looks like a solid square. When i click the place of the buttons an "X" still shows up so they are still there, but what am i missing that is making them blend together?

Winning combo code is:

```
    if ((b1.getText() == "X") && (b2.getText() == "X") && (b3.getText() == "X"))
    {
        disableButtons();
        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congrats! You Win!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

EDIT here are images of whats happening
[image: first]

[image: second]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the background image back to the default 9patch image. Try this:

```
b1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
b2.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
b3.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```

Comment: No worries! Could you mark this as the correct answer for any other users that come across this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove this line :

```
b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

Comment: I have the winning combo being colored RED

Comment: So I'm just changing that value back to gray

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby Post some more code, and screenshots of what you are seeing. What you are describing seems odd.

Comment: I am trying to edit my post but it keeps telling me i have some wrong formatted code even though it looks fine

Comment: okay I got a couple pictures up and the code for how i set the button color to red

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby I'm glad you got it work but I would suggest you start a new game with a new `Intent` with clear top flag instead of trying to toggle back and forth the state of all the buttons, it will make the code simpler and cleaner.